# Recursive JavaScript Function to Build FancyTree JSON

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, fancytree

I am trying to build an array of JSON objects for FancyTree (https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/TutorialLoadData). However, my JSON source (Jira REST service) can have pretty much any structure, so the code to build the array of JSON objects has to be entirely generic and able to handle pretty much anything.

Here is an example of the source JSON:

```
{
"feed": {
    "entry": [
        {
            "expand": "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
            "id": "95743",
            "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/issue/95743",
            "key": "XYZ-24600",
            "fields": {
                "MandatoryReviewersInternal": [
                    {
                        "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10947",
                        "value": "Test",
                        "id": "10947",
                        "disabled": false
                    }
                ],
                "PlannedDropDate": "2022-02-01",
                "assignee": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/user?username=swchambe",
                    "name": "swchambe",
                    "key": "swchambe",
                    "emailAddress": "sharon.w.chamberlain@foo.com",
                    "displayName": "Sharon W Chamberlain",
                    "active": true,
                    "timeZone": "America/Chicago"
                },
                "ESBEnvironments": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10120",
                    "value": "All Environments",
                    "id": "10120",
                    "disabled": false
                },
                "RestrictedInformation": "Do not include Proprietary, ITAR or SBU restricted information in this action",
                "subtasks": [
                    {
                        "id": "96160",
                        "key": "XYZ-24601",
                        "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/issue/96160",
                        "fields": {
                            "summary": "Test 1",
                            "status": {
                                "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/status/10338",
                                "description": "",
                                "iconUrl": "foo.comjira/images/icons/statuses/generic.png",
                                "name": "Current",
                                "id": "10338",
                                "statusCategory": {
                                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/statuscategory/4",
                                    "id": 4,
                                    "key": "indeterminate",
                                    "colorName": "yellow",
                                    "name": "In Progress"
                                }
                            },
                            "issuetype": {
                                "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/issuetype/10319",
                                "id": "10319",
                                "description": "",
                                "iconUrl": "foo.comjira/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=11747&avatarType=issuetype",
                                "name": "Affected Document",
                                "subtask": true,
                                "avatarId": 11747
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "96466",
                        "key": "XYZ-24614",
                        "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/issue/96466",
                        "fields": {
                            "summary": "Test 2",
                            "status": {
                                "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/status/10338",
                                "description": "",
                                "iconUrl": "foo.comjira/images/icons/statuses/generic.png",
                                "name": "Current",
                                "id": "10338",
                                "statusCategory": {
                                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/statuscategory/4",
                                    "id": 4,
                                    "key": "indeterminate",
                                    "colorName": "yellow",
                                    "name": "In Progress"
                                }
                            },
                            "issuetype": {
                                "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/issuetype/10319",
                                "id": "10319",
                                "description": "",
                                "iconUrl": "foo.comjira/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=11747&avatarType=issuetype",
                                "name": "Affected Document",
                                "subtask": true,
                                "avatarId": 11747
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "Participants": [
                    {
                        "name": "djcook2(djcook2xyz)"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "swchambe(swchambexyz)"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "r_slscdm(JIRAxyz)"
                    }
                ],
                "reporter": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/user?username=djcook2",
                    "name": "djcook2",
                    "key": "djcook2",
                    "emailAddress": "deborah.j.ott@foo.com",
                    "displayName": "Deborah Jane Ott",
                    "active": true,
                    "timeZone": "America/Chicago"
                },
                "CPEOrganization": "xyz",
                "SFSearchandViewLink": "<a href=foo.comportal/web/csa/search?key=95743&projectKey=XYZ&issueType=Change%20Request>S2D-0637</a>",
                "progress": {
                    "progress": 0,
                    "total": 0
                },
                "issuetype": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/issuetype/8",
                    "id": "8",
                    "description": "Request for a change to the way the application works.",
                    "iconUrl": "foo.comjira/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=11737&avatarType=issuetype",
                    "name": "Change Request",
                    "subtask": false,
                    "avatarId": 11737
                },
                "project": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/project/13390",
                    "id": "13390",
                    "key": "XYZ",
                    "name": "Configuration Status Accounting",
                    "projectTypeKey": "business"
                },
                "SFIdentifier": "S2D-0637",
                "watches": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/issue/XYZ-24600/watchers",
                    "watchCount": 2,
                    "isWatching": true
                },
                "ServerEnvironment": [
                    {
                        "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10060",
                        "value": "Production",
                        "id": "10060",
                        "disabled": false
                    }
                ],
                "ScheduleImpact": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/12245",
                    "value": "No",
                    "id": "12245",
                    "disabled": false
                },
                "MissionConfigurationDefinition": [
                    {
                        "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/12246",
                        "value": "1110-1200",
                        "id": "12246",
                        "disabled": false
                    },
                    {
                        "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/12247",
                        "value": "1110-2200",
                        "id": "12247",
                        "disabled": false
                    }
                ],
                "updated": "2022-05-23T10:06:45.000-0500",
                "description": "¶ Paragraph\nNonbreaking   Hyphen\nEm Space\nEn Space\n½ One Half Fraction\n¼ One Quarter Fraction\n¾ Three Quarters Fraction\n10⁵ superscript\n6⁵ superscript\nO₂ subscript\n\n± 0177\n≤ 2264\n≥ 2265\n\n10⁰ - 2070\n10¹ - 00B9\n10³ - 00B3\n10² - 00B2\n10⁴ - 2074\n10⁵ - 2075\n10⁶ - 2076\n10⁷ - 2077\n10⁸ - 2078\n10⁹ - 2079\n\nΑ  0391\nΒ  0392\nΓ  0393\nΔ  0394\nΕ  0395",
                "CRStatus": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10050",
                    "value": "In Work",
                    "id": "10050",
                    "disabled": false
                },
                "summary": "SLS-FSW-SAN-21-0010    SLS FSW Software Authorization Notice (SAN) - PARMD5 Support Tool Release 14.0",
                "SLSPriority": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10347",
                    "value": "Routine",
                    "id": "10347",
                    "disabled": false
                },
                "TestStatus": [
                    {
                        "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10041",
                        "value": "Not Tested",
                        "id": "10041",
                        "disabled": false
                    }
                ],
                "ChangeJustificationRationale": "Looks good to me, but who am I?",
                "CostImpact": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/19251",
                    "value": "No",
                    "id": "19251",
                    "disabled": false
                },
                "ExternalReviewType": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10370",
                    "value": "Mandatory",
                    "id": "10370",
                    "disabled": false
                },
                "CROffice": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10342",
                    "value": "SLS",
                    "id": "10342",
                    "disabled": false
                },
                "Rank": "0|i0c9r8:",
                "CrossProgram": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10294",
                    "value": "No",
                    "id": "10294",
                    "disabled": false
                },
                "Programassignedto": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10295",
                    "value": "SLS",
                    "id": "10295",
                    "disabled": false
                },
                "Programassignedby": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10301",
                    "value": "SLS",
                    "id": "10301",
                    "disabled": false
                },
                "ChangeType": [
                    {
                        "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10307",
                        "value": "Programmatic",
                        "id": "10307",
                        "disabled": false
                    }
                ],
                "ChangePackageManagerCPM": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/user?username=swchambe",
                    "name": "swchambe",
                    "key": "swchambe",
                    "emailAddress": "sharon.w.chamberlain@foo.com",
                    "displayName": "Sharon W Chamberlain",
                    "active": true,
                    "timeZone": "America/Chicago"
                },
                "ChangePackageManagerAlternateCPMAlternate": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/user?username=slcraig",
                    "name": "slcraig",
                    "key": "smclemo2",
                    "emailAddress": "shanda.craig@foo.com",
                    "displayName": "Shanda L Craig",
                    "active": true,
                    "timeZone": "America/Chicago"
                },
                "ChangePackageEngineerCPE": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/user?username=cbowab",
                    "name": "cbowab",
                    "key": "cbowab",
                    "emailAddress": "cheri.f.bowab@foo.com",
                    "displayName": "Cheri F Bowab",
                    "active": true,
                    "timeZone": "America/Chicago"
                },
                "status": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/status/10631",
                    "description": "",
                    "iconUrl": "foo.comjira/images/icons/statuses/generic.png",
                    "name": "Draft",
                    "id": "10631"
                },
                "Development": "{}",
                "RequestedDate": "2021-05-13",
                "Risk": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10273",
                    "value": "No",
                    "id": "10273",
                    "disabled": false
                },
                "creator": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/user?username=djcook2",
                    "name": "djcook2",
                    "key": "djcook2",
                    "emailAddress": "deborah.j.ott@foo.com",
                    "displayName": "Deborah Jane Ott",
                    "active": true,
                    "timeZone": "America/Chicago"
                },
                "aggregateprogress": {
                    "progress": 0,
                    "total": 0
                },
                "AssigneeSecurityScan": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/user?username=sbattles",
                    "name": "sbattles",
                    "key": "sbattles",
                    "emailAddress": "sylvia.battles@foo.com",
                    "displayName": "Sylvia M Battles",
                    "active": true,
                    "timeZone": "America/Chicago"
                },
                "Board": [
                    {
                        "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10259",
                        "value": "XYZ",
                        "id": "10259",
                        "disabled": false
                    }
                ],
                "MissionEffectivity": [
                    {
                        "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/19754",
                        "value": "XYZ",
                        "id": "19754",
                        "disabled": false
                    },
                    {
                        "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/19756",
                        "value": "AC01",
                        "id": "19756",
                        "disabled": false
                    }
                ],
                "CRNumber": [
                    {
                        "name": "XYZ-0637"
                    }
                ],
                "created": "2021-05-14T15:14:22.000-0500",
                "ASCBBoardDate": "2021-05-18",
                "InitiatorOrganization": "ED10",
                "CPMAssignedDate": "2021-05-14",
                "CRAssignedDate": "2021-05-14",
                "ImpactstoCertifiedData": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/20152",
                    "value": "No",
                    "id": "20152",
                    "disabled": false
                },
                "ASCBReviewSuspenseDate": "2021-05-18",
                "TopLevelLinkTitle": "SV02854 S2D-0637",
                "TopLevelLinkURL": "https://nasa-ice.nasa.gov/Windchill/app/#ptc1/tcomp/infoPage?ContainerOid=OR%3Awt.inf.library.WTLibrary%3A3451955009&oid=OR%3Awt.folder.SubFolder%3A4352888087&u8=1",
                "Initiator": {
                    "self": "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/user?username=kmoorhea",
                    "name": "kmoorhea",
                    "key": "kmoorhea",
                    "emailAddress": "kathy.h.moorhead@foo.com",
                    "displayName": "Kathy H Moorhead",
                    "active": true,
                    "timeZone": "America/Chicago"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I need to end up with an array of JSON objects that looks like this:

```
[
{title: "Node 1", key: "1"},
{title: "Folder 2", key: "2", folder: true, children: [
  {title: "Node 2.1", key: "3", myOwnAttr: "abc"},
  {title: "Node 2.2", key: "4"},
  {title: "Folder 3", key: "5", folder: true, children: [
    {title: "Node 3.1", key: "6", myOwnAttr: "xyz"},
    {title: "Node 3.2", key: "7"}
  ]}
]}
]
```

Here is my current attempt. It is not working as desired.

```
const createTreeJson = function(){
let treeJson = [];
let treeJsonObj = {};
//loop entry array, but there is only ever 1
feedJson.feed.entry.forEach((entry) => {
    treeJsonObj = {};
    //items
    treeJsonObj.title = "Item";
    treeJsonObj.folder = true;
    let children = [];
    //loop object properties
    Object.entries(entry).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        children.push(createTreeJsonObject(children, key, value));
    });
    treeJsonObj.children = children;
    treeJson.push(treeJsonObj);
});

console.log(treeJson);
}

const createTreeJsonObject = function(children, key, value){
console.log(key, value);
if(value.constructor.name === "Object"){
    //it's an object
    let subChildren = [];
    Object.entries(value).forEach(([key2, value2]) => {
        subChildren.push(createTreeJsonObject(subChildren, key2, value2));
    });
    children.push({
        "title": key,
        "folder": true,
        "children": subChildren
    });
}else if(value.constructor.name === "Array"){
    //it's an array
}else{
    //it's something else
    children.push({
        "key": key,
        "title": `${key}`,
        "tooltip": `${value}`
    });
}

return children;
};

createTreeJson();
```

Note: feedJson in the code is the above source JSON. I did not want to repeat it again in the code. You can also see it in a Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ua8vm9p7/1/

I am open to using something like loadash to help with this if it makes it easier. I do have jQuery available too, but am trying to stay away from it.

I can't seem to quite get the logic right. Has anyone done this kind of thing before? Can anyone lend a hand on how I can do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: I am still working on a solution, but my current attempt is causing an infinite loop, so I don't want to post it. Hopefully, I will have something more stable soon and can post it.

Comment: Can you harmonise the expected output with the sample input? I have no idea what you consider to be a node in the input.

Comment: Please post your code even if not working as you can always update it later.  You are more likely to receive help if you demonstrate an attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: As for harmonizing the output with the input, every object attribute should become a node in the tree. You can see a sample of it  [here](https://prnt.sc/zVvn1eAZCc0z). Obviously, the undefined nodes need to go away.

Comment: Code has been posted.

Comment: This part -> `children.push(createTreeJsonObject(children, key, value));` (and the similar subchildren part) - `createTreeJsonObject` accepts and returns `children` so by pushing the result to children you are getting into a weird state.  Instead just do `createTreeJsonObject(children, key, value)`

Comment: Please make a smaller example where the input and the requested output match correctly. You probably don't need more than twenty or so nodes in the whole tree to demonstrate the behavior you want. Trying to extract requirements from (non-working) code is problematic at best.

Comment: @James, That did it! I knew I was close, but couldn't get over the hump. Thanks so much! Recursion makes my head spin oOoOo

Answer (score 1):

I think simpler code will do this:

```js
const makeFancyMenu = (obj) =>
  Object .entries (obj) .flatMap (([k, v]) =>
    Array .isArray (v)
      ? []
    : Object (v) === v
      ? [{title: k, folder: true, children: makeFancyMenu (v)}]
      : [{key: k, title: `${k}`, tooltip: v}]
  )

const convert = (obj) =>
  obj .feed .entry .map ((o) => ({
    title: 'Item',
    folder: true, 
    children: makeFancyMenu (o)
  }))

const input = {feed: {entry: [{expand: "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations", id: "95743", self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/issue/95743", key: "XYZ-24600", fields: {MandatoryReviewersInternal: [{self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10947", value: "Test", id: "10947", disabled: !1}],PlannedDropDate: "2022-02-01", assignee: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/user?username=swchambe", name: "swchambe", key: "swchambe", emailAddress: "sharon.w.chamberlain@foo.com", displayName: "Sharon W Chamberlain", active: !0,timeZone: "America/Chicago"},ESBEnvironments: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10120", value: "All Environments", id: "10120", disabled: !1},RestrictedInformation: "Do not include Proprietary, ITAR or SBU restricted information in this action", subtasks: [{id: "96160", key: "XYZ-24601", self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/issue/96160", fields: {summary: "Test 1", status: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/status/10338", description: "", iconUrl: "foo.comjira/images/icons/statuses/generic.png", name: "Current", id: "10338", statusCategory: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/statuscategory/4", id: 4,key: "indeterminate", colorName: "yellow", name: "In Progress"}},issuetype: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/issuetype/10319", id: "10319", description: "", iconUrl: "foo.comjira/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=11747&avatarType=issuetype", name: "Affected Document", subtask: !0,avatarId: 11747}}},{id: "96466", key: "XYZ-24614", self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/issue/96466", fields: {summary: "Test 2", status: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/status/10338", description: "", iconUrl: "foo.comjira/images/icons/statuses/generic.png", name: "Current", id: "10338", statusCategory: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/statuscategory/4", id: 4,key: "indeterminate", colorName: "yellow", name: "In Progress"}},issuetype: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/issuetype/10319", id: "10319", description: "", iconUrl: "foo.comjira/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=11747&avatarType=issuetype", name: "Affected Document", subtask: !0,avatarId: 11747}}}],Participants: [{name: "djcook2(djcook2xyz)"},{name: "swchambe(swchambexyz)"},{name: "r_slscdm(JIRAxyz)"}],reporter: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/user?username=djcook2", name: "djcook2", key: "djcook2", emailAddress: "deborah.j.ott@foo.com", displayName: "Deborah Jane Ott", active: !0,timeZone: "America/Chicago"},CPEOrganization: "xyz", SFSearchandViewLink: "<a href=foo.comportal/web/csa/search?key=95743&projectKey=XYZ&issueType=Change%20Request>S2D-0637</a>", progress: {progress: 0,total: 0},issuetype: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/issuetype/8", id: "8", description: "Request for a change to the way the application works.", iconUrl: "foo.comjira/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=11737&avatarType=issuetype", name: "Change Request", subtask: !1,avatarId: 11737},project: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/project/13390", id: "13390", key: "XYZ", name: "Configuration Status Accounting", projectTypeKey: "business"},SFIdentifier: "S2D-0637", watches: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/issue/XYZ-24600/watchers", watchCount: 2,isWatching: !0},ServerEnvironment: [{self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10060", value: "Production", id: "10060", disabled: !1}],ScheduleImpact: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/12245", value: "No", id: "12245", disabled: !1},MissionConfigurationDefinition: [{self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/12246", value: "1110-1200", id: "12246", disabled: !1},{self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/12247", value: "1110-2200", id: "12247", disabled: !1}],updated: "2022-05-23T10: 06: 45.000-0500", description: "¶ Paragraph\nNonbreaking   Hyphen\nEm Space\nEn Space\n½ One Half Fraction\n¼ One Quarter Fraction\n¾ Three Quarters Fraction\n10⁵ superscript\n6⁵ superscript\nO₂ subscript\n\n± 0177\n≤ 2264\n≥ 2265\n\n10⁰ - 2070\n10¹ - 00B9\n10³ - 00B3\n10² - 00B2\n10⁴ - 2074\n10⁵ - 2075\n10⁶ - 2076\n10⁷ - 2077\n10⁸ - 2078\n10⁹ - 2079\n\nΑ  0391\nΒ  0392\nΓ  0393\nΔ  0394\nΕ  0395", CRStatus: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10050", value: "In Work", id: "10050", disabled: !1},summary: "SLS-FSW-SAN-21-0010    SLS FSW Software Authorization Notice (SAN) - PARMD5 Support Tool Release 14.0", SLSPriority: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10347", value: "Routine", id: "10347", disabled: !1},TestStatus: [{self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10041", value: "Not Tested", id: "10041", disabled: !1}],ChangeJustificationRationale: "Looks good to me, but who am I?", CostImpact: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/19251", value: "No", id: "19251", disabled: !1},ExternalReviewType: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10370", value: "Mandatory", id: "10370", disabled: !1},CROffice: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10342", value: "SLS", id: "10342", disabled: !1},Rank: "0|i0c9r8: ", CrossProgram: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10294", value: "No", id: "10294", disabled: !1},Programassignedto: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10295", value: "SLS", id: "10295", disabled: !1},Programassignedby: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10301", value: "SLS", id: "10301", disabled: !1},ChangeType: [{self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10307", value: "Programmatic", id: "10307", disabled: !1}],ChangePackageManagerCPM: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/user?username=swchambe", name: "swchambe", key: "swchambe", emailAddress: "sharon.w.chamberlain@foo.com", displayName: "Sharon W Chamberlain", active: !0,timeZone: "America/Chicago"},ChangePackageManagerAlternateCPMAlternate: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/user?username=slcraig", name: "slcraig", key: "smclemo2", emailAddress: "shanda.craig@foo.com", displayName: "Shanda L Craig", active: !0,timeZone: "America/Chicago"},ChangePackageEngineerCPE: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/user?username=cbowab", name: "cbowab", key: "cbowab", emailAddress: "cheri.f.bowab@foo.com", displayName: "Cheri F Bowab", active: !0,timeZone: "America/Chicago"},status: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/status/10631", description: "", iconUrl: "foo.comjira/images/icons/statuses/generic.png", name: "Draft", id: "10631"},Development: "{}", RequestedDate: "2021-05-13", Risk: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10273", value: "No", id: "10273", disabled: !1},creator: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/user?username=djcook2", name: "djcook2", key: "djcook2", emailAddress: "deborah.j.ott@foo.com", displayName: "Deborah Jane Ott", active: !0,timeZone: "America/Chicago"},aggregateprogress: {progress: 0,total: 0},AssigneeSecurityScan: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/user?username=sbattles", name: "sbattles", key: "sbattles", emailAddress: "sylvia.battles@foo.com", displayName: "Sylvia M Battles", active: !0,timeZone: "America/Chicago"},Board: [{self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10259", value: "XYZ", id: "10259", disabled: !1}],MissionEffectivity: [{self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/19754", value: "XYZ", id: "19754", disabled: !1},{self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/19756", value: "AC01", id: "19756", disabled: !1}],CRNumber: [{name: "XYZ-0637"}],created: "2021-05-14T15: 14: 22.000-0500", ASCBBoardDate: "2021-05-18", InitiatorOrganization: "ED10", CPMAssignedDate: "2021-05-14", CRAssignedDate: "2021-05-14", ImpactstoCertifiedData: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/20152", value: "No", id: "20152", disabled: !1},ASCBReviewSuspenseDate: "2021-05-18", TopLevelLinkTitle: "SV02854 S2D-0637", TopLevelLinkURL: "https: //nasa-ice.nasa.gov/Windchill/app/#ptc1/tcomp/infoPage?ContainerOid=OR%3Awt.inf.library.WTLibrary%3A3451955009&oid=OR%3Awt.folder.SubFolder%3A4352888087&u8=1", Initiator: {self: "foo.comjira/rest/api/2/user?username=kmoorhea", name: "kmoorhea", key: "kmoorhea", emailAddress: "kathy.h.moorhead@foo.com", displayName: "Kathy H Moorhead", active: !0,timeZone: "America/Chicago"}}}]}}

console .log (convert (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here, `makeFancyMenu` does all the recursive heavy lifting, and `convert` simply wraps it in something that handles the differences at the root.

Instead of `map` we use `flatMap` and wrap its single callback returns in arrays so that in the case of an array property, we can just return an empty array.  This is a simple way to combine `filter` and `map`.